# How to make string representation of ObjectIds without having to specify it for each member

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with the official MongoDb driver for C#.

My domain objects all have an Id property of type string

```
string Id { get; set;}
```

but I want to store 12 bytes binary ObjectIds in the actual database, and this is achieved in the class map like so:

```
  BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<X>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id).SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
  });
```

Foreign ObjectId key to other collection are also represented as string and should also be saved as Objects ids.

Now, I don't want to write the same SetRepresenttion stuff for each and every Id and foreign key if I can avoid it.

So is there a way to say just once and for all, that all string  Id fields should be represented as ObjectIds in the db AND all string properties with name  ending in "Id" should also be rpresented as ObjectIds in the db ?

Comment: WHY? Why is this voted down? Without even leaving a comment?

Comment: seems a fair question to me

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this as in the answer below links have changed and doesnt give me much to go on from the docs.

Comment: There is a convention which you can try to use I post it in this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621787/4319938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a convention called ISerializationOptionsConvention.  Have a look at the docs here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Writeacustomconvention.

Using this you will be able test for the members type being a string and the name ending with "Id", and then assign it your serialization options.

Comment: The link seems to be leading to a different page that does Not mention anything about ISerializationOptionsConvention.  Could you please point out some other resources that given detailed explanations about the ISerializationOptionsConvention usage?

Comment: New documentation is here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/.