# using string for mongodb _id

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a json document that I entered into my mongo db using the mongoimport command.
I set it's _id to "MyDocId", looking at it in mongo, the _id is correctly set.
in my C# code, I want to read this document using this _id:

```
ObjectId id = ObjectId.Parse("MyDocId");
```

I am getting an exception in the above code

Comment: There is a convention which you can try to use I post it in this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621787/4319938

Answer (score 15):

You may need to use a Bson attribute on your property like so.

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

There is quite a good explanation of these attributes in this answered question

[BsonId vs BsonRepresentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871416/difference-between-decorating-a-property-in-c-sharp-with-bsonrepresentationbson)

Comment: How does it work with filter query builders?

//Not fetching any documents
collection.FindAsync(Builders<MyObj>.Filter.Where(x=>x.Id == "stringvalue"))

//Gives syntax error (can't company ObjectId & string)
collection.FindAsync(Builders<MyObj>.Filter.Where(x=>x.Id == ObjectId.Parse("stringvalue")))

Answer (score 5):

Since version 2.9 of `MongoDB.Driver` you can also use built-in convention [StringIdStoredAsObjectIdConvention](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Conventions_StringIdStoredAsObjectIdConvention.htm)

```
        var pack = new ConventionPack
        {
            new StringIdStoredAsObjectIdConvention()
        };

        ConventionRegistry.Register("Custom Convention", pack, t => true);
```

Answer (score 2):

ObjectId parse will only parse strings that have a [valid format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectId). In your case, if the document's `_id` is a string, you don't need to parse it as an ObjectId, just use the string value in your query.

Comment: I create a filter like so: Builders<PropertyHelperLookup>.Filter.Eq("_id", this._docId) and I am getting an exception

Comment: What is the exception?