# Mongo C# deserialize ObjectId to string

Tags: string, mongodb, bson, objectid

I've changed all my C# entities from this:

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

because I need to use Rebus and send the Id around, but ObjectId is not serializable without adding a custom serializer. And actually string is more convenient in other places (e.g.: model binding in MVC Controllers).

Anyway, I thought the change would be without problems but now my I get an exception trying to deserialize ObjectId to string: my ApplicationUser class has a

```
IEnumerable<string> Friendships { get; set; }
```

containing a list of Ids from the Friendship entity. They were created as ObjectId but now I want to handle them as string... how can I handle this in code now?

Comment: There is a convention which you can try to use I post it in this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621787/4319938

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't set Id as ObjectId

Set it as a string with those attributes

`[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]`
`[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]`

`public string ID { get; set; }`