# Mongo do not generate ObjectId automatically via fulent API

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm migrating from Mongo Driver 1.x to 2.x and encountered with a problem that Mongo do not simply generate the ID for a document.

Entity:

```
public sealed class History
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long BusinessId { get; set; }
    public ShowcaseVersion Version { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
cm.AutoMap();
cm.MapIdMember(c => c.Id)
    .SetIgnoreIfDefault(true)
    .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
    .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
```

Insert:

```
Collection.InsertOne(new History
{
    BusinessId = businessId,
    Version = version
});
```

Result:

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: showcases.History index: *id*
>   dup key: { : null }

Comment: turn public string Id in public ObjectId Id? Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go for ObjectId instead string than change it to ObjectId and I think it should work.

But if you want to use string like you do this post might be answer: [using string for mongodb _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094634/using-string-for-mongodb-id)

Comment: Yep, it does work with `ObjectId`. But the problem here that this DTO is declared in API assembly and I just can't reference MongoDriver there, it should be configured outside this class AND use `string` because being said I cannot reference assembly where `ObjectId` is declared. However, very useful answer :)

Comment: I need to make my testing enviroment to help you. When I catch time I will do it.